# Deploy contract didnt resolve the promise

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs

im facing a problem deploying a simple smart contract.

When i use ganacha-cli, the program enter in a loop of **confimation** event, counting from 1.
Thats the first problem.

Output:

```
Account: 0xd5f75a4F58da4dF050F84dedF07d24f7bf388F8F
trans hash: 0x1ab65a58debce4859a7df358ba54653fe0727b25f9d483622ab412ea7c49a56d
receipt: [object Object]
Contract address: 0xd2039ADAE2a61fADd65C4bec6a7791b2B6e56d08
confirmation: 1
confirmation: 2
confirmation: 3
confirmation: 4
confirmation: 5
...
```

And when i use a blockchain runing with geth in a server, the **send** method never is resolved. Only transaction hash is fired, and the contract is created in the blockchain. The second and main problem.

Output:

```
Account: 0xb5cF1ee3481B45d1A1cB939921f3f6E3f0C97f80
trans hash: 0x387a881262fbfee430bf761724bb5e21706fc2c76bb86dfd69aff526c46b985f
```

Code (web3 version 1.2):

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPPP'));

var account = '0xb5cF1ee3481B45d1A1cB939921f3f6E3f0C97f80'

console.log('Account: ' + account);

web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account, "dos", 50000)

const deployedContract = new web3.eth.Contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"displayMessage","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"displayMessagex","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);

deployedContract.deploy({
    data: '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'
}).send({
    from: account,
    gas: 10000000
})
.once('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
    console.log('confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber)
})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    console.log('trans hash: ' + hash)
})
.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('error: ' + error)
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
    console.log('receipt: ' + receipt.toString())
})
.then(function(contract) {
    console.log('Contract address: ' + contract.options.address);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Geth command:

```
geth --port 3000 --networkid 87936 --nodiscover --datadir=. --maxpeers=0  --rpc --rpcport 8543 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Thanks!

After start mining the main problem convert in the first problem (is an advance), changed the on('confirmation') to once('confirmation') the output now is:

```
Account: 0xb5cF1ee3481B45d1A1cB939921f3f6E3f0C97f80
trans hash: 0xc5a2dc489815c205a53658bf5ebcde95593e83da4ead07355fcae4d722636c12
confirmation: 0
receipt: [object Object]
Contract address: 0x6b4A76Ab26e487Fdc502779Abc438d0cF59299bc
```

Comment: you run geth on your private chain or ethereum mainnet?

Comment: On private chain.

Comment: Make sure that your chain is mining?

Comment: lol i forgot to start mining. But now, never end the call.

Comment: What do you mean about the never end?

Comment: Sorry, i realized that is listen all time the event 'on'... i need to unsubscribe that. I removed the 'on' and works. Do u know how to unsubcribe 'on'?

Comment: According to the spec, on confirmation will raise up to 24th block confirmation. Then it depends on what you want to do on each event. I don’t think it’s a never end .

Answer (score 0):

The `.on` method attaches an event handler to the deploy function, which listens to all the `confirmation` events fired when a new block is created after your deployment transaction gets mined.

Change `.on` to `.once` will let the code proceed.

Comment: Thanks, thats solve the problem with ganacha, but not the main problem

Comment: Let me get it clear. Your "main problem" is that the `send` method is not resolved. However, you mentioned that there's a new contract instance deployed, which means that `send` is effective. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: This didn't work for me